# How to make a UINavigationController a specific width on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have been really pulling my hair out over this.

How can I make a UINavigationController a specific width on the iPad.  I have tried all sorts of things to change the frame, but nothing seems to work.  I want it to look a bit like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://gilsmethod.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/make-facetime-call-ipad-201.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can add a navigation bar from the library by dragging and dropping to your view.
And you can set the IBOutlet for this navigation bar.

Comment: @Cameron asked about adding a UINavigationController, not a UINavigationBar.